# error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'itrac_rnd', Scriptrunner for Jira written for automation rule

Tags: sql, database, automation, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am using the following code to query my database in scriptrunner for Jira. I am receiving the following error
[image]

How can I print which object names are available? That way, I know what query to use.
package SuperFeature

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.label.LabelManager
import SuperFeature.Configuration_SuperFeature
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.Driver
import java.sql.*

def log = Logger.getLogger('atlassian-jira.log')
def driver = Class.forName('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver').newInstance() as Driver // <1>
 
def props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("user", "webM_Feature") // <2>
props.setProperty("password", "webM_Feature")
String connectstmt= "jdbc:sqlserver://ireport:1433;RND_webM_Feature="
log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA "+connectstmt)


 def conn = driver.connect(connectstmt, props) // <3>
 def sql = new Sql(conn)


 
try {

    
    String query = "SELECT cycle, line, prod, fcomp, sfcomp, pm, rnd FROM dbo.itrac_rnd"
    ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {

                log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA "+rs.getString("cycle"))
                
            }
} finally {
    sql.close()
    conn.close()
}
```

Comment: It seems the queried table cannot found. It may be because of the syntax. Can you change `dbo.itrac_rnd` as `[dbo].[itrac_rnd]` please? (Not sure about it so not writing it as answer ;))